# How to move several params to another node in jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have to generate strange json from object(with jackson ObjectMapper), something like:

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Json"
   },
   "userType":"MD"
}
```

But, with jackson data-bind i can do only:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Json",
   "userType":"MD"
}
```

With User.class:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String userType;

//Getters Setters Constructor
```

I found two ways of bypassing. First one - to use another "superclass":

```
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private User user;
    private String userType;
//Getters Setters Constructor
```

Second way - to use Map:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("data", user);
        map.put("userType", "MD");
        String json = objMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

But i think, that it's not idea to use this ways if i have about 8 different objects with such structure. So, what's best pratice? Or maybe there are another built in ways?
I want to find the best one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach you mentioned is the best practice, but it is called Composition (HAS-A relationship) rather 'superclass' and just to add readability, you can refactor your classes like this:

```
public class User {
    private Data data;
    private String userType;

//Getters Setters Constructor
}


public class Data {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

So, when you marshal your pojo to json, structure will be:

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Json"
   },
   "userType":"MD"
}
```

which is what you want! Happy coding :)

Update: If you are generating your API documentation with Swagger or Open API Spec, then there is no way to have a representation of your model if you use Map or HashMap. So, obviously, the first approach is the one you should consider!

Comment: Every object has different data parameters and unique fields, so.. in this way i have to do lot of "magic" with params, annotations and getters/setters

Comment: @newSqlz any of API need to have at least of possible attributes which may be different in case of each request, and to ignore them, you can use `@JsonIgnore` or other annotation to marshal properly, but do maintain good documentation, you need to have data structure or class to represent your object.

Comment: @newSqlz I mean to say, you need to have a specific contract and this is properly maintainable only though Pojo objects, which is class representation of the object... use Map only to manipulate the data, not to represent the data or have contract

Comment: Ok, you're right. no another way. i made custom serializator, but it's pack to data every object that extends abstract api model :)